# Using special characters in python Popen call

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm working on a python 2.7 application that is intended to upload files to a 2007 Sharepoint. The server is running on a OpenSUSE machine. The way I'm doing this right now is to use subprocess' Popen to execute a curl command. However, python raises UnicodeEncodeError when the filename has special characters ('á', 'õ', 'ç', e.g.).

I could work around the Unicode Error by forcing a conversion
from str to Unicode for the command string, but then the file goes to Sharepoint with a bad formatting name (Manutenção becomes Manuten'c~ao, for instance). The following image describes the implementation of the functions I'm using: [functions used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGIg9.jpg)

Does anyone have a clue on how should I proceed?

**P.S.:** I would prefer to stay with the curl command for the execution of the request, but we're open to other solutions

**EDIT:** Didn't try pycurl, but I'll take a look on it. The Linux dist running the server is 3.11.10.
The execution flow is as following:

1. Read the file name and path from a utf-8 database
2. Choose the destination url for file in Sharepoint
3. Build a curl command similar to "*curl --ntlm -u usr:pwd --upload-file filelocalPath fileSharepointUrl -k*"
4. Use the convert_to_utf_8 function (check attached image)
5. Use Popen to make the request (as in __execute_curl_cmd_and_wait function)

Comment: Where does the python application run (*nix or Windows) ? Did you try to use pycurl ? Try to provide more information according to [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No, I didn't try it, I'll take a look on it. I just edited my post, hope it helps...

Comment: Converting `Manutenção` into `Manuten'c~ao` doesn't sound like something either curl or Python would be doing. Are you sure your Sharepoint server isn't mangling the names? What are the exact headers curl is sending (found with `curl -vv ...`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guys, I figured out the problem

Since I was running my code on a Linux machine, the Popen command was encoded in utf-8 and sent to Sharepoint this way. However, it seems the encoding used by Sharepoint 2007 is some of latin-1 or windows-1252.

I came to this conclusion after running that same code on a Windows machine and encoding the line with a bunch of other encodings. As expected, the upload went OK whenever the encoding was windows-1252 or latin-1 (recognized by the win cmd).

Thanks for the replies.